# Javascript Regular Expression not matching

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Morning All

I have a javascript regular expression that doesn't work correctly and I'm not sure why.

I'm calling the API at https://uptimerobot.com, and getting back a JSON string with details of the monitor statues. This is however wrapped in a function call syntax. Like this:

```
jsonUptimeRobotApi({MASKED-STATUES-OBJ})
```

As this call is being made from a generic script I was hoping to test the response to see if it had this type of syntax wrapping then parse it accordingly.

However I can't seem to find a RegEx syntax to match the logic:

- Start of string
- An unknown number of characters [a-zA-Z]
- Open parentheses
- Open brace
- An unknown number of any character
- Close brace
- Close parentheses
- End of string

This looks right:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\(\{.*\}\)$
```

And works in regex101: https://regex101.com/r/sE7dM6/1

However it fails in my code and via jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/po49pww3/1/

The "m" was added in regex101 as the actual string is much longer, and failed to match without it, however a number of small tweeks that I've tried havn't resulted in a match in jsFiddle.

Anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape all the backslashes one more time because within `"` delimiters, you must escape the backslash one more time or otherwise it would be treated as an escape sequence.

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+\\(\\{.*\\}\\)$", "m");
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/po49pww3/2/)

Comment: Because using a string literal :)

Comment: Thanks guys, had just got there myself https://jsfiddle.net/po49pww3/4/ Always the way, typing the question gives you enough of a break to look at the problem afresh.

Comment: ☆ CoNgRaTs  100k  Avinash! 